# get uint value inside a bytes32 slice

Tags: solidity, assembly, bytes

I have the following code:

```
function test_bytes(bytes32 test) external pure returns(bytes3 idx,uint256 idx2)
    {   

        //test = 0x885094be76a41df2b315d2e669de00bb0fa1333efa1fe9d200e304c490989680

        assembly{
            calldatacopy(0x0,33,36)
            idx := mload(0x0)  //0x989680
            idx2 := mload(add(idx, 32))  //10000000 
        }
```

the idx value gets bytes3 equal to 0x989680 which is correct, that value is required to convert to uint256 and store it in idx2. With the function shown I get a gas error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly are you trying to do. But if you want to extract the last 3 bytes from the `test` parameter I would do it in the following way

```
contract X {
    function test_bytes(bytes32 test) external pure returns(bytes3 idx,uint256 idx2) {   
        // test = 0x885094be76a41df2b315d2e669de00bb0fa1333efa1fe9d200e304c490989680

        assembly {
            idx := shl(sub(256, 24), test)
            idx2 := and(test, 0xffffff)
        }
    }
}
```

- `idx` is declared as bytes3 so we need to move the bytes we need to the "left". I do that with the shift left operator `shl(sub(256, 24), test)`.
- `idx2` is declared as uint256 so the interesting bits must be to the right. Since the bytes are already there we only need to mask out the last bytes `and(test, 0xffffff)`.